# Adding a CNAME record could affect to the mail service?

Tags: domains, dns, subdomain, dns-servers

I´ve been searching about this and I have found different answer for it. So I would like to explain the context. I don´t understand much about DNS records, so maybe one of you could help me.
Currently. I have a domain on a website, the domain works as a mail server as well.
I would like to transfer the domain to a new website, and it seems that the only thing I need to do its to create a CNAME record to points to the subdomain of the new website and other configurations that the platform of the new website told me to do (Outside of the DNS control panel)
Adding the CNAME record would affect the mail service?
I have a MX records pointing from my domain (*example.com*) to the email *service example-com.mail.eo.outlook.com.*
And the one thing I would do is to point my current CNAME record to the new website
Current CNAME record: *[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)* pointing to *oldwebsite.net*
CNAME record after the change: *[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)* pointing to *newwebsite.com*

I was told specifically that I can´t bring the mail service down so. Maybe if the previous action will affect my mail server, Could you recommend me other methods to do it without having to take my mail service down?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CNAME CAN affect mail service but you should be OK based on the scenario you describe.

Setting up a CNAME for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) should be OK (provided your email is at example.com), but a CNAME for example.com would break DNS - including breaking email delivery, and is a fairly common mistake because CNAMES do not work the way many people assume they do.

If you use an A record with the IP address instead of a CNAME this will alleviate any possible problem with email as long as your email uses MX records (which is standard).

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. Sadly I don´t count with the IP address, just the subdomain. By the way, based on what you have told me, currently, I have a CNAME with the subdomain ftp.example.com that its pointing to example.com, Does this also cause that my email service got break?

Comment: `but a CNAME for example.com` which is totally impossible per DNS specifications you can't have a `CNAME` record at apex, because there is already `NS` and `SOA` records there and the `CNAME` can no cohabit with other records. This is "emulated" by various providers with proprietary local solutions called `ALIAS` or `APEXCNAME`, etc. Today, the correct solution for this is to use DNS HTTPS(/SVCB) records.

Comment: I don´t have that much knowledge about domains, but I have tried point the domain to another subdomain with CNAME and it worked successfully. The difference here is that this domain have a mail service, and the other one doesn´t. Even if they have the NS records, those NS are provided by the old website platform, since the new one doesn´t provide me new NS.

Comment: having a subdomain pointing to another domain is fine in most cases - including here.  It is only where the parent domain points to a CNAME that you normally need to worry, which is not the case here.    You should NEVER point the whole domain to a CNAME - as @PatrickMevzek correctly says this breaks DNS.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek  I agree with the sentiment you expressed, but I think it would be better to say that A CNAME at the APEX breaks the DNS specification (ie it is possible - in fact easy to do on most nameservers, it just does not work correctly) .    I disagree that HTTPS/SVCB records are the correct solution as they are not yet an accepted standard - they are a good solution and do have excellent modern browser support, but not ubiquitous DNS server support, and they can break some APIs (AFAIK Curl does not support it, and RFC9460 is still a PROPOSED standard)

Comment: To be clear, the risks of using CNAMES is when using it as the apex (start of) the  domain you want to redirect from - you are OK to redirect TO the apex of another domain.  As I said in my answer you are OK as long as its a subdomain of your "FROM" domain.

Comment: @davidgo I am afraid to not see the point of "ie it is possible - in fact easy to do on most nameservers, it just does not work correctly)" If it does not work why do it? So it is not a sentiment. Specifications are specifications and for systems to interoperate everyone has to follow them. As for your "sentiment" on HTTPS/SVCB they are already a defacto standard as supported by multiple browsers and cloud providers. They also offer a proper solution to the problem with additional benefits. What about "break some APIs"? Can you explain? Not "not supported" but "break"?

Comment: "To be clear, the risks of using CNAMES is when using it as the apex " Stop pushing bad ideas clearly and unambiguously against the specifications. CNAME at apex are forbidden and it is foolish to push for them. They do not work, point blank, nothing to go further.

Comment: "in fact easy to do on most nameservers" Can you cite one nameserver that allows to load a zone with such case?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek   First one I tried - powerdns.  (I use that for authorative nameservers so easy to test).   Its been a while, but while BIND will not actually load the zone, I believe it fails to do so fairly silently except for in the logs...

Comment: "First one I tried - powerdns. " What did you try? Just loading the zone or making the supposed CNAME at apex resolve (as a CNAME)? Please show dig outputs.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Making the apex resolve.  Try a query on test.me against nameaerver 60.234.67.225

Comment: No reply from that IP. Feel free to show output of `dig CNAME test.me @60.234.67.225`. But even if that is published that doesn't prove in any way it works, as it is subject to resolver asking for that and no sane resolver will ever will...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek  Sorry, that IP was wrong  (cellphone and fat fingers) - try 60.234.77.225.  (You could be) but I'm not sure you are right about no resolver asking for it - I just did a dig [at]60.234.77.225 test.me and it returned the CNAME and the A record.   Interesting - Trying that when asking for an NS record surprisingly also worked - it used the CNAME for host.net.nz and then used that to resolve the NS records for my nameservers from host.net.nz - asking for the CNAME record also worked.

Comment: Thank you to all. I used only the cname record and it change successfully and doesn´t affect the mail server. Have a nice day!